# Waiting for client side Javascript to load with Axios GET request

Tags: javascript, node.js, get, axios

What I'm trying to do is sync my work schedule with my Google Calendar. Now there isn't an API available so that's not an option, unfortunately. I'm able to successfully log in to my account and redirect to the page with the content. The only problem is that the site relies on client-side javascript that loads in the dates, etc.

Is there any way to have Axios wait a few seconds so the dates can load in and then return the body contents? I've been looking around the internet but couldn't find any answers to my question.

This is the code I'm using right now.

```
axios.post('link here', {
    Username: 0,
    Password: 0
}).then((res) => {
    axios.get('link here', {headers: {
        "Cookie":res.headers['set-cookie']}}, {}).then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data)
    });
});
```

So I'm looking for a way to let it load the page and then return `res.data`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible with axios.
What the browser does is it fetches the html (like your `get` call) and renders any dynamic content by executing the javascript linked to the html

Axios will simply return the raw html and since it is not a browser you won't get anything else.

If you are absolutely sure there aren't any api integrations ala: https://developers.google.com/calendar, you can use https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer instead.

Puppeteer, unlike axios, will render the page and run any linked javascript for you. Its a headhless chrome browser that you can control via javascript. That's the right tool for this job.

Alternatively, instead of fetching the raw HTML, you can figure out what calls the javascript function is executing instead (probably a get call to another link)